# Webpack nodejs fs.readFile is not a function

Tags: node.js, webpack, fs

I have a webpack config like:

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
        filename:'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
        ]
    },
    node: {
      fs: "empty"
    }
};
```

And I want to read a file using `fs`

I am doing something like:

```
var fs = require('fs')
console.log(fs)

fs.readFile('input.txt', function (err, buffer) {
        console.log("buffer")
        console.log(buffer)


    })
```

I just want to read a file here but when I do this it gives me error saying:

> `fs.readFile` is not a function

I have installed `fs` using `npm install --save fs`

Also when I print `fs` it gives me empty object.
Above I have done `console.log(fs)` it is giving me empty object

What is wrong in here?

Comment: Remove `node: { fs: "empty" }` and add `target: 'node'`: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target

Comment: well this gives me process is not defined error

Comment: You trying to run this code from browser? In browser, obviously, there is not any access to file system.

Comment: this means I should start a development server ??

Comment: You should run it as `node ./bundle.js`

Comment: actually I am starting tthe server with python -m SimpleHTTPServer

Comment: The `fs` module is part of node. You shouldn't install it.

Comment: @doubledherin Yes but when you run a Front-End server you have to run it through the bundle, not through the Node WebServer.

Answer (score 4):

As I believe the comments mentioned,

```
node: { fs: "empty" }
```

Needs to be removed.
Moreover, all your code must run on the server.  You cannot read files like this in the browser. Node APIs are server-side only, so you would need to build an API using express or some similar library
e.g.

```
    router.get('/file/read', (req, res, next) => { fs.readFile('input.txt', function (err, buffer) {
            console.log("buffer")
            res.send(buffer);
        }) 
    })
```

Then in your browser you would need to use AJAX to call the API and retrieve the file contents.

Reading arbitrary files has **OBVIOUS SECURITY ISSUES** . You should not allow the api to read any files the user likes.  You should be very careful here to restict input and limit the set of files available.