# Validate at Runtime whether Typescript Object matches an Interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsonschema, ajv

I have a React app written in Typescript. I am attempting to determine at runtime whether an object matches my Typescript interface.

Here are some options that won't work for me:

- I do not want to write a typeguard since my interface is often changing and is large.
- I already have, stored outside of my React app's src/ folder, a JSON representation of the interface's schema generated using [the typescript-json-schema package](https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema). However, I cannot reference this JSON file since `fs.readFileSync` and other similar read functions do not work from browsers (this is a security feature; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319299/webpack-nodejs-fs-readfile-is-not-a-function) for one explanation).

Here is my current attempt to generate a runtime schema object using typescript-json-schema, then validate it using [AJV](https://ajv.js.org/):

```
  const program = TJS.getProgramFromFiles([resolve(FILE_PATH_TO_INTERFACE_DEFINITION)]);
  const schema = TJS.generateSchema(program, INTERFACE_NAME);
  const validate = new Ajv().compile(schema!);
  return validate(data);
```

`FILE_PATH_TO_TYPE_DEFINITIONS` is inside my React app's src/ directory.

The error with this specific code is `type undefined not found` when generating the schema on line 2. I'm looking for explanations/solutions for this particular error **or** other approaches that would work (since even when I tweak the code to avoid this particular error I run into other issues, which makes me think I'm missing something bigger about AJV or about typescript-json-schema.).